# status update not working

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, jsf-2

When I am clicking the Speak Out(p:commandButton) to submit a status, I am getting the following exception. The exception is caused by commentList() function by the line

```
Query query = em.createQuery(
    "SELECT c FROM Comment c WHERE c.statusId=" + statusId,
    Comment.class);
```

1)Home.xhtml

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core">
<h:head>
</h:head>

    <div style="width: 100%; background-color: #EEEEEE;">
        <h:panelGrid columns="1">
            <h:form id="speakout">
                <h:outputText value="Speak Out" />
                <br />
                <h:outputText value="Share whats in your mind.!"
                    style="color:#aaaaaa;font-size:x-small;" />
                <p:inputTextarea name="content" id="sharetext" cols="60" rows="2"
                    onclick="this.value='';" value="#{statusBean.status.statusmsg}"
                    style="text-size:small;" />
                <br />
                <p:commandButton type="submit" value="Speak Out"
                    action="#{statusBean.save}" ajax="false"
                    styleClass="buttonstyle" />
                <br />
            </h:form>
        </div>
        <!--  -->
        <div class="items">
            <h:form>
                <ui:repeat var="p" value="#{statusBean.statusList}">
                    <ui:fragment rendered="#{p.statusmsg!=null}">
                        <div class="status">
                            <!--  for text status msg check-->
                            <h:commandLink action="#{friendBean.gotoFriendProfile(p.email)}"
                                styleClass="link">
                                <img src="../images/profilePicture/thumb/#{p.picture}"
                                    style="height: 39px; width: 39px;" />&nbsp;
                                <h:outputText value="#{p.statusBy}:" />
                            </h:commandLink>
                            <h:outputText value="#{p.statusmsg}" styleClass="textstyle1" />
                            <h:outputText value="#{p.timeMillis}"
                                style="font-size:xx-small;float:right;color:#bbbbbb;font-style: italic;">
                                <f:converter converterId="timeConverter" />
                            </h:outputText>
                            <h:commandLink action="#{statusBean.deleteStatus(p.statusId)}"
                                value="Delete"></h:commandLink>
                            <p:growl />
                            <br />
                            <ui:repeat var="q" value="#{statusBean.commentList(p.statusId)}" >
                                <div class="barcomment">
                                    <br />
                                        <h:commandLink action="#{friendBean.gotoFriendProfile(q.email)}"
                                            styleClass="link">
                                            <img src="../images/profilePicture/thumb/#{q.picture}"
                                                style="height: 29px; width: 29px;" />&nbsp;
                                            <h:outputText value="#{q.commentBy}:" />
                                        </h:commandLink>
                                        <h:outputText value=" #{q.comment}" styleClass="textstyle1" />
                                        <h:outputText value="#{q.timeMillis}"
                                            style="font-size:xx-small;float:right;font-style: italic;">
                                            <f:converter converterId="timeConverter" />
                                        </h:outputText>
                                        <h:commandLink action="#{statusBean.deleteComment(q.commentId)}"
                                            value="Delete"></h:commandLink>
                                    </div>
                                </ui:repeat>
                                <br />
                                <div class="comment">
                                    <p:inputText value="#{statusBean.comment.comment}"
                                        styleClass="box" />
                                    <p:commandLink value="Views"
                                        action="#{statusBean.update(p.statusId)}"
                                        ajax="false" styleClass="link" />
                                </div>
                                <br />
                            </div>
                        </ui:fragment>
                    </ui:repeat>
                </h:form>
            </div>
        </h:body>
</html>
```

2) Status Bean

```
 package com.bean;



    public class StatusBean {
        Date d;
        Comment comment;
        Status status;
        private EntityManager em;
        private UploadedFile uploadedFile;

        public Comment getComment() {
            return comment;
        }

        public void setComment(Comment comment) {
            this.comment = comment;
        }

        public Status getStatus() {
            return status;
        }

        public void setStatus(Status status) {
            this.status = status;
        }

        public StatusBean() {
            d = new Date();
            comment = new Comment();
            status = new Status();
            EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence
                    .createEntityManagerFactory("FreeBird");
            em = emf.createEntityManager();
        }



        public List<Status> getStatusList() {
            FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
            HttpSession session = (HttpSession) context.getExternalContext()
                    .getSession(true);
            User user = (User) session.getAttribute("userdet");
            Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT s FROM Status s WHERE s.email='"
                    + user.getEmail() + "' ORDER BY s.timeMillis desc",
                    Status.class);
            List<Status> results = query.getResultList();
            Query query1 = em.createQuery("SELECT f FROM Friend f WHERE f.email='"
                    + user.getEmail() + "'", Friend.class);
            List<Friend> results1 = query1.getResultList();
            Iterator<Friend> it = results1.listIterator();
            while (it.hasNext()) {
                String email = it.next().getFriendEmail();
                Query query2 = em.createQuery(
                        "SELECT s FROM Status s WHERE s.email='" + email
                                + "' ORDER BY s.timeMillis desc", Status.class);
                List<Status> results2 = query2.getResultList();
                results.addAll(results2);

            }
            Collections.sort(results);
            int index = 0;
            int end = index+5 > results.size() ? results.size() : index+5;
            List<Status> subList = results.subList(0, end);

            session.setAttribute("statusindex", end);
            return subList;

        }
    public String save() {
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    HttpSession session = (HttpSession) context.getExternalContext()
            .getSession(false);
    User user = (User) session.getAttribute("userdet");
    status.setEmail(user.getEmail());
    status.setStatusBy(user.getFirstName());
    d = new Date();
    status.setTimeMillis(d.getTime());
    status.setPicture(user.getImage());
    System.out.println("status save called");
    em.getTransaction().begin();
    em.persist(status);
    em.getTransaction().commit();
    FacesContext context2 = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    context2.getExternalContext().getSessionMap().remove("statusBean");
    return "success";
}


        public String update(String statusId) {

            System.out.println("Update Called...");
            FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
            HttpSession session = (HttpSession) context.getExternalContext()
                    .getSession(true);
            User user = (User) session.getAttribute("userdet");
            comment.setStatusId(Integer.parseInt(statusId));
            comment.setCommentBy(user.getFirstName());
            comment.setPicture(user.getImage());
            comment.setEmail(user.getEmail());
            d = new Date();
            comment.setTimeMillis(d.getTime());
            em.getTransaction().begin();
            em.persist(comment);
            em.getTransaction().commit();
            getComment().setComment("");
            FacesContext context2 = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
            context2.getExternalContext().getSessionMap().remove("statusBean");
            return "success";

        }

        public List<Comment> commentList(String statusId) {
            FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
            Query query = em.createQuery(
                    "SELECT c FROM Comment c WHERE c.statusId=" + statusId,
                    Comment.class);
            List<Comment> results = query.getResultList();
            return results;
        }

        public String deleteStatus(String statusId) {

            Status status = em.find(Status.class, Integer.parseInt(statusId));
            FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
            HttpSession session = (HttpSession) context.getExternalContext()
                    .getSession(true);
            User user = (User) session.getAttribute("userdet");
            if (user.getEmail().equals(status.getEmail())) {
                em.getTransaction().begin();
                em.remove(status);
                em.getTransaction().commit();

            } else {
                context.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(
                        "You don't have permission to delete"));
            }

            return "success";

        }

        public String deleteComment(String commentId) {

            Comment comment = em.find(Comment.class, Integer.parseInt(commentId));
            FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
            HttpSession session = (HttpSession) context.getExternalContext()
                    .getSession(true);
            User user = (User) session.getAttribute("userdet");
            Status status = em.find(Status.class, comment.getStatusId());
            if (user.getEmail().equals(status.getEmail())
                    || comment.getEmail().equals(user.getEmail()))

            {
                em.getTransaction().begin();
                em.remove(comment);
                em.getTransaction().commit();
            } else {
                context.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(
                        "You don't have permission to delete"));
            }
            return "success";

        }

    }
```

3)Exception

```
Mar 03, 2013 9:10:26 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [Faces Servlet] in context with path [/FreeBird_v.6] threw exception [An exception occurred while creating a query in EntityManager: 
Exception Description: Syntax error parsing the query [SELECT c FROM Comment c WHERE c.statusId=], line 0, column -1: unexpected end of query.
Internal Exception: NoViableAltException(-1@[792:1: comparisonExpressionRightOperand returns [Object node] : (n= arithmeticExpression | n= nonArithmeticScalarExpression | n= anyOrAllExpression );])] with root cause
NoViableAltException(-1@[792:1: comparisonExpressionRightOperand returns [Object node] : (n= arithmeticExpression | n= nonArithmeticScalarExpression | n= anyOrAllExpression );])
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.libraries.antlr.runtime.DFA.noViableAlt(DFA.java:159)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.libraries.antlr.runtime.DFA.predict(DFA.java:144)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.parsing.jpql.antlr.JPQLParser.comparisonExpressionRightOperand(JPQLParser.java:4326)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.parsing.jpql.antlr.JPQLParser.comparisonExpression(JPQLParser.java:4215)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.parsing.jpql.antlr.JPQLParser.simpleConditionalExpressionRemainder(JPQLParser.java:3389)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.parsing.jpql.antlr.JPQLParser.simpleConditionalExpression(JPQLParser.java:3326)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.parsing.jpql.antlr.JPQLParser.conditionalPrimary(JPQLParser.java:3275)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.parsing.jpql.antlr.JPQLParser.conditionalFactor(JPQLParser.java:3194)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.parsing.jpql.antlr.JPQLParser.conditionalTerm(JPQLParser.java:3103)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.parsing.jpql.antlr.JPQLParser.conditionalExpression(JPQLParser.java:3029)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.parsing.jpql.antlr.JPQLParser.whereClause(JPQLParser.java:2986)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.parsing.jpql.antlr.JPQLParser.selectStatement(JPQLParser.java:380)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.parsing.jpql.antlr.JPQLParser.document(JPQLParser.java:281)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.parsing.jpql.JPQLParser.parse(JPQLParser.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.parsing.jpql.JPQLParser.buildParseTree(JPQLParser.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.buildEJBQLDatabaseQuery(EJBQueryImpl.java:215)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.buildEJBQLDatabaseQuery(EJBQueryImpl.java:190)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.<init>(EJBQueryImpl.java:142)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.<init>(EJBQueryImpl.java:126)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.createQuery(EntityManagerImpl.java:1475)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.createQuery(EntityManagerImpl.java:1497)
    at com.bean.StatusBean.commentList(StatusBean.java:227)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.invoke(BeanELResolver.java:484)
    at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.invoke(CompositeELResolver.java:161)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:159)
    at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:189)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:106)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.component.UIRepeat.getValue(UIRepeat.java:268)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.component.UIRepeat.getDataModel(UIRepeat.java:244)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.component.UIRepeat.setIndex(UIRepeat.java:434)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.component.UIRepeat.doVisitChildren(UIRepeat.java:642)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.component.UIRepeat.visitTree(UIRepeat.java:600)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1487)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.component.UIRepeat.visitTree(UIRepeat.java:606)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1487)
    at javax.faces.component.UIForm.visitTree(UIForm.java:331)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1487)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1487)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.deliverPostRestoreStateEvent(RestoreViewPhase.java:258)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.execute(RestoreViewPhase.java:245)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:97)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.doPhase(RestoreViewPhase.java:107)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:114)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:308)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1001)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:579)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Comment: _SELECT c FROM Comment c WHERE c.statusId=_ this is not a valid SQL, that's why you are getting error.

Comment: Where is the save method in StatusBean ?

Comment: I have deleted it before posting it here so the code is minimal.If you want I can add the save method.

Comment: @AvinashSingh have added uploaded the save method also.

Comment: This code is very inefficient. [You're doing business job in getter methods](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2090033/why-jsf-calls-getters-multiple-times/2090062#2090062). Every iteration will unnecessarily hit the DB again and again. You should have a `@ManyToOne List<Comment> comments` field in `Status` class and use `#{status.comments}` instead.

Comment: @BalusC What does `@Many toOne` annotation do. It would be really helpful if you show me a small example

Comment: Look in your JPA tutorial/book under the chapter "relationships". In the JSF end you just need to make sure that you never write anything else in getters than just a single line `return propertyName;` (unless you really understand what you're doing).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like `p.statusId` which you are passing to `commentList(String statusId)` is empty. You can try to put `System.out.println("statusId: "+statusId);` to begining of `commentList(String statusId)` method.

You can also put `<h:outputText value="p.statusId: #{p.statusId}"/>` just before:

```
<ui:repeat var="q" value="#{statusBean.commentList(p.statusId)}" >
```

I'm also not sure if it's good practice to put `statusBean.commentList(p.statusId)` in `ui:repeat` `value` attribute. You can end up retrieving list of Statuses from DB more often than you wanted to. It would be better to preload it to some property and then pass it where required.

**UPDATE**

Also replace:

```
Query query = em.createQuery(
    "SELECT c FROM Comment c WHERE c.statusId=" + statusId, Comment.class);
```

with

```
TypedQuery<Comment> query = em.createQuery(
    "SELECT c FROM Comment c WHERE c.statusId = :statusId", Comment.class);
query.setParameter("statusId", statusId);
```

This way your queries are safer against SQL injection and syntax errors.

**UPDATE 2**

```
private class StatusWrapper {

  private Status status;
  private List<Comment> comments;

}
```

In your StatusBean

```
...
private List<StatusWrapper> statuses;
...
(getters setters)
...
public StatusBean() {
...
initStatuses();
}
...
public void initStatuses() {
  statuses=new ArrayList<>();
  List<Status> stats=getStatusList();
  for(Status status:stats) {
    StatusWrapper wrapper=new StatusWrapper();
    wraper.setStatus(status);
    wraper.setComments(commentList(status.getStatusId()));
    statuses.add(wrapper);
}
```

Than in your page just use statuses property. Hope it's clear (there are some typos probably.)

Comment: i have checked it using `<h:outputText value="p.statusId: #{p.statusId}"/>` before `ui:repeat var="q" value="#{statusBean.commentList(p.statusId)}" > `. The value is getting printed

Comment: I think p.statusId is not being passed when using `<ui:repeat var="q" value="#{statusBean.commentList(p.statusId)}" >` but I don't know why it is getting printed when I am using `<h:outputText value="p.statusId: #{p.statusId}"/>`

Comment: So you should put breakpoint or `System.out.println("statusId: "+statusId);` to `commentList()` method. Or as I said, preload the list and than use it.

Comment: I am basically new to jsf, so it would be really helpful if you suggest me how I can preload the list before using it.

Comment: Hope it's clear. Its just quick outline. Later you can add lazy loading, leverage JPA associations etc.

Comment: The bean part is clear to me, but how should I implement it int the xhtml, like what should I use instead of `<ui:repeat var="q" value="#{statusBean.commentList(p.statusId)}">`.

Comment: You should replace  `<ui:repeat var="p" value="#{statusBean.statusList}">` with  `<ui:repeat var="p" value="#{statusBean.statuses}">` and than every occurence of `p` with `p.status` and also
`<ui:repeat var="q" value="#{statusBean.commentList(p.statusId)}">` with `<ui:repeat var="q" value="#{q.comments}">`. Is it clearer now?

Comment: Hey thanks for explaining it so nicely, now everything is running except the comment, whenever I comment on the status the comment is posted as null, the property statusBean.comment.comment is not binding with backing bean and also whenever I am trying to delete the status or the comment I am getting null pointer exception.