# Comment to a status is not working

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, jsf-2

When I am loading the page for the first time everything is working fine, I am having no exception.Status updates are shown with their corresponding comments but whenever I try to comment on status by clicking views(p:commandLink button) I am getting the following exception

1)Home.xhtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core">


<h:head>

</h:head>




            <div style="width: 100%; background-color: #EEEEEE;">
                <h:panelGrid columns="1">
                    <h:form id="speakout">
                        <h:outputText value="Speak Out" />
                        <br />
                        <h:outputText value="Share whats in your mind.!"
                            style="color:#aaaaaa;font-size:x-small;" />
                        <p:inputTextarea name="content" id="sharetext" cols="60" rows="2"
                            onclick="this.value='';" value="#{statusBean.status.statusmsg}"
                            style="text-size:small;" />
                        <br />

        <p:commandButton type="submit" value="Speak Out"
                            action="#{statusBean.save}" ajax="false" styleClass="buttonstyle" />
                        <br />
                    </h:form>

            </div>

            <!--  -->
            <div class="items">
            <h:form>
                <ui:repeat var="p" value="#{statusBean.statusList}">


                        <ui:fragment rendered="#{p.statusmsg!=null}">
                            <div class="status">
                                <!--  for text status msg check-->
                                <h:commandLink action="#{friendBean.gotoFriendProfile(p.email)}"
                                    styleClass="link">
                                    <img src="../images/profilePicture/thumb/#{p.picture}"
                                        style="height: 39px; width: 39px;" />&nbsp; <h:outputText
                                        value="#{p.statusBy}:" />
                                </h:commandLink>
                                <h:outputText value="#{p.statusmsg}" styleClass="textstyle1" />
                                <h:outputText value="#{p.timeMillis}"
                                    style="font-size:xx-small;float:right;color:#bbbbbb;font-style: italic;">
                                    <f:converter converterId="timeConverter" />
                                </h:outputText>
                                <h:commandLink action="#{statusBean.deleteStatus(p.statusId)}"
                                    value="Delete"></h:commandLink>
                                <p:growl />
                                <br />

                                <ui:repeat var="q" value="#{statusBean.commentList(p.statusId)}" >
                                    <div class="barcomment">
                                        <br />
                                        <h:commandLink
                                            action="#{friendBean.gotoFriendProfile(q.email)}"
                                            styleClass="link">
                                            <img src="../images/profilePicture/thumb/#{q.picture}"
                                                style="height: 29px; width: 29px;" />&nbsp; <h:outputText
                                                value="#{q.commentBy}:" />
                                        </h:commandLink>
                                        <h:outputText value=" #{q.comment}" styleClass="textstyle1" />
                                        <h:outputText value="#{q.timeMillis}"
                                            style="font-size:xx-small;float:right;font-style: italic;">
                                            <f:converter converterId="timeConverter" />
                                        </h:outputText>
                                        <h:commandLink
                                            action="#{statusBean.deleteComment(q.commentId)}"
                                            value="Delete"></h:commandLink>
                                    </div>

                                </ui:repeat>
                                <br />
                                <div class="comment">
                                    <p:inputText value="#{statusBean.comment.comment}"
                                        styleClass="box" />
                                    <p:commandLink value="Views"
                                        action="#{statusBean.update(p.statusId)}" ajax="false"
                                        styleClass="link" />
                                </div>
                                <br />
                            </div>
                        </ui:fragment>


                </ui:repeat>
</h:form>
            </div>


</h:body>
</html>
```

2) Status Bean

```
package com.bean;



public class StatusBean {
    Date d;
    Comment comment;
    Status status;
    private EntityManager em;
    private UploadedFile uploadedFile;

    public Comment getComment() {
        return comment;
    }

    public void setComment(Comment comment) {
        this.comment = comment;
    }

    public Status getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(Status status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public StatusBean() {
        d = new Date();
        comment = new Comment();
        status = new Status();
        EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence
                .createEntityManagerFactory("FreeBird");
        em = emf.createEntityManager();
    }

        public String save() {
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    HttpSession session = (HttpSession) context.getExternalContext()
            .getSession(false);
    User user = (User) session.getAttribute("userdet");
    status.setEmail(user.getEmail());
    status.setStatusBy(user.getFirstName());
    d = new Date();
    status.setTimeMillis(d.getTime());
    status.setPicture(user.getImage());
    System.out.println("status save called");
    em.getTransaction().begin();
    em.persist(status);
    em.getTransaction().commit();
    FacesContext context2 = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    context2.getExternalContext().getSessionMap().remove("statusBean");
    return "success";
}

    public List<Status> getStatusList() {
        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        HttpSession session = (HttpSession) context.getExternalContext()
                .getSession(true);
        User user = (User) session.getAttribute("userdet");
        Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT s FROM Status s WHERE s.email='"
                + user.getEmail() + "' ORDER BY s.timeMillis desc",
                Status.class);
        List<Status> results = query.getResultList();
        Query query1 = em.createQuery("SELECT f FROM Friend f WHERE f.email='"
                + user.getEmail() + "'", Friend.class);
        List<Friend> results1 = query1.getResultList();
        Iterator<Friend> it = results1.listIterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            String email = it.next().getFriendEmail();
            Query query2 = em.createQuery(
                    "SELECT s FROM Status s WHERE s.email='" + email
                            + "' ORDER BY s.timeMillis desc", Status.class);
            List<Status> results2 = query2.getResultList();
            results.addAll(results2);

        }
        Collections.sort(results);
        int index = 0;
        int end = index+5 > results.size() ? results.size() : index+5;
        List<Status> subList = results.subList(0, end);

        session.setAttribute("statusindex", end);
        return subList;

    }



    public String update(String statusId) {

        System.out.println("Update Called...");
        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        HttpSession session = (HttpSession) context.getExternalContext()
                .getSession(true);
        User user = (User) session.getAttribute("userdet");
        comment.setStatusId(Integer.parseInt(statusId));
        comment.setCommentBy(user.getFirstName());
        comment.setPicture(user.getImage());
        comment.setEmail(user.getEmail());
        d = new Date();
        comment.setTimeMillis(d.getTime());
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        em.persist(comment);
        em.getTransaction().commit();
        getComment().setComment("");
        FacesContext context2 = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        context2.getExternalContext().getSessionMap().remove("statusBean");
        return "success";

    }

    public List<Comment> commentList(String statusId) {
        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        Query query = em.createQuery(
                "SELECT c FROM Comment c WHERE c.statusId=" + statusId,
                Comment.class);
        List<Comment> results = query.getResultList();
        return results;
    }

    public String deleteStatus(String statusId) {

        Status status = em.find(Status.class, Integer.parseInt(statusId));
        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        HttpSession session = (HttpSession) context.getExternalContext()
                .getSession(true);
        User user = (User) session.getAttribute("userdet");
        if (user.getEmail().equals(status.getEmail())) {
            em.getTransaction().begin();
            em.remove(status);
            em.getTransaction().commit();

        } else {
            context.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(
                    "You don't have permission to delete"));
        }

        return "success";

    }

    public String deleteComment(String commentId) {

        Comment comment = em.find(Comment.class, Integer.parseInt(commentId));
        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        HttpSession session = (HttpSession) context.getExternalContext()
                .getSession(true);
        User user = (User) session.getAttribute("userdet");
        Status status = em.find(Status.class, comment.getStatusId());
        if (user.getEmail().equals(status.getEmail())
                || comment.getEmail().equals(user.getEmail()))

        {
            em.getTransaction().begin();
            em.remove(comment);
            em.getTransaction().commit();
        } else {
            context.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(
                    "You don't have permission to delete"));
        }
        return "success";

    }

}
```

3)Exception

```
Mar 03, 2013 9:10:26 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [Faces Servlet] in context with path [/FreeBird_v.6] threw exception [An exception occurred while creating a query in EntityManager: 
Exception Description: Syntax error parsing the query [SELECT c FROM Comment c WHERE c.statusId=], line 0, column -1: unexpected end of query.
Internal Exception: NoViableAltException(-1@[792:1: comparisonExpressionRightOperand returns [Object node] : (n= arithmeticExpression | n= nonArithmeticScalarExpression | n= anyOrAllExpression );])] with root cause
NoViableAltException(-1@[792:1: comparisonExpressionRightOperand returns [Object node] : (n= arithmeticExpression | n= nonArithmeticScalarExpression | n= anyOrAllExpression );])
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.libraries.antlr.runtime.DFA.noViableAlt(DFA.java:159)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.libraries.antlr.runtime.DFA.predict(DFA.java:144)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.parsing.jpql.antlr.JPQLParser.comparisonExpressionRightOperand(JPQLParser.java:4326)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.parsing.jpql.antlr.JPQLParser.comparisonExpression(JPQLParser.java:4215)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.parsing.jpql.antlr.JPQLParser.simpleConditionalExpressionRemainder(JPQLParser.java:3389)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.parsing.jpql.antlr.JPQLParser.simpleConditionalExpression(JPQLParser.java:3326)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.parsing.jpql.antlr.JPQLParser.conditionalPrimary(JPQLParser.java:3275)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.parsing.jpql.antlr.JPQLParser.conditionalFactor(JPQLParser.java:3194)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.parsing.jpql.antlr.JPQLParser.conditionalTerm(JPQLParser.java:3103)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.parsing.jpql.antlr.JPQLParser.conditionalExpression(JPQLParser.java:3029)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.parsing.jpql.antlr.JPQLParser.whereClause(JPQLParser.java:2986)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.parsing.jpql.antlr.JPQLParser.selectStatement(JPQLParser.java:380)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.parsing.jpql.antlr.JPQLParser.document(JPQLParser.java:281)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.parsing.jpql.JPQLParser.parse(JPQLParser.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.parsing.jpql.JPQLParser.buildParseTree(JPQLParser.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.buildEJBQLDatabaseQuery(EJBQueryImpl.java:215)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.buildEJBQLDatabaseQuery(EJBQueryImpl.java:190)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.<init>(EJBQueryImpl.java:142)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.<init>(EJBQueryImpl.java:126)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.createQuery(EntityManagerImpl.java:1475)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.createQuery(EntityManagerImpl.java:1497)
    at com.bean.StatusBean.commentList(StatusBean.java:227)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.invoke(BeanELResolver.java:484)
    at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.invoke(CompositeELResolver.java:161)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:159)
    at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:189)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:106)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.component.UIRepeat.getValue(UIRepeat.java:268)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.component.UIRepeat.getDataModel(UIRepeat.java:244)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.component.UIRepeat.setIndex(UIRepeat.java:434)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.component.UIRepeat.doVisitChildren(UIRepeat.java:642)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.component.UIRepeat.visitTree(UIRepeat.java:600)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1487)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.component.UIRepeat.visitTree(UIRepeat.java:606)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1487)
    at javax.faces.component.UIForm.visitTree(UIForm.java:331)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1487)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1487)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.deliverPostRestoreStateEvent(RestoreViewPhase.java:258)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.execute(RestoreViewPhase.java:245)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:97)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.doPhase(RestoreViewPhase.java:107)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:114)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:308)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1001)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:579)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [status update not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15187480/status-update-not-working)

Comment: Dude, do you have double account on SO? You have two pairs of completely same questions with user user2129151?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Exception Description: Syntax error parsing the query [SELECT c FROM Comment c WHERE c.statusId=], line 0, column -1: unexpected end of query.`

It would appear that when you are building your SQL statement, you are appending an empty value on the end.

It also seems like that this block of code is your issue.

```
 public List<Comment> commentList(String statusId) {
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    Query query = em.createQuery(
            "SELECT c FROM Comment c WHERE c.statusId=" + statusId,
            Comment.class);
    List<Comment> results = query.getResultList();
    return results;
}
```

You can solve this by checking to ensure that `statusId != null`.

Comment: That might help me solve the problem temporarily.Actually when I am loading the page for first time(Home.xhtml) statusId is being passed but I don't get it why it is not being passed when I am commenting on a status using the views button(p:commandLink)

Comment: Have you tried Printing out the value of statusID when update is called?

Comment: and im assuming the same syntax works for the other functions?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25478/discussion-between-amlan-karmakar-and-chris-cooney)

Comment: If you read the whole code wall (and visit the link marked as duplicated), you would understand that the problem is sending this `statusId` inside the `<ui:repeat>` as stated in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15188438/1065197).